# How to have beautiful soup fetch emails?

Tags: python, email, beautifulsoup

Im working with beautiful soup and would like to grab emails to a depth of my choosing in my web scraper. Currently however I am unsure why my web scraping tool is not working. Everytime I run it, it does not populate the email list.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re
import urllib
import threading

def step2():
    file = open('output.html', 'w+')
    file.close()
    # links already added
    visited = set()
    visited_emails = set()
    scrape_page(visited, visited_emails, 'https://www.google.com', 2)

    print('Webpages \n')
    for w in visited:
        print(w)

    print('Emails \n')
    for e in visited_emails:
        print(e)

# Run recursively
def scrape_page(visited, visited_emails, url, depth):

    if depth == 0:
    return

    website = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a', email=False))

    emails = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", str(website))

    first = str(website).split('mailto:')
    for i in range(1, len(first)):
        print(first.split('>')[0])

    for email in emails:
        if email not in visited_emails:
            print('- got email ' + email)
            visited_emails.add(email)


    for link in soup:
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            if link['href'] not in visited:
                if link['href'].startswith('https://www.google.com'):
                    visited.add(link['href'])
                    scrape_page(visited, visited_emails, link['href'], depth - 1)

def main():
    step2()

main()
```

for some reason im unsure how to fix my code to add emails to the list. if you could give me some advice it would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: display `str(website)` and check it - maybe there is no emails in text - you scrape `google` which doesn't like bots and it can send page with warrning :)

Comment: Why are you using a regex?

Comment: @furas google was just a test example. for some reason none of the websites i tried didnt work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i tried used regex to to find if it follows the format of an email

Answer (score 1):

You just need to look for the href's with mailto:

```
emails = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('a[href^=mailto:]')]
```

I presume  https://www.google.com is a placeholder for the actual site you are scraping as there are no mailto's to scrape on the google page. If there are mailto's in the source you are scraping then this will find them.

Comment: hmm that dosnt seem to be working either for me. Could there be anything else wrong with the emails not populating?

Comment: @alecxe, after two hours of looking at things like  `f(n) is O(g(n)) ≡ ∃C ∃k ∀n (n > k → f(n) ≤ C g(n))` I needed something a little less mentally taxing ;)

Comment: @ChristinaChen, you need to provide a little sample input or some url where you are running the code.